# Netbeans, Blank Available Classes box

Tags: class, netbeans

Ok, so I am new to netbeans. I am trying to import a project. 
http://freesourcecode.net/javaprojects/15562/A-simple-dice-game-in-Java#.VS2Bm_nF8pU

That project, I eventually managed to do so. When I attempt to run it, I get an "Browse available Classes" message, except its blank.

I only have the stuff listed in that link and it has 3 Different Class files, shouldn't at least 1 of those be showing up there?

So how do I get Classes to be listed here for me to actually run it

Comment: Hope you're not still looking for answer. Similarly, I found same. But after a bit more Googleing, found it is solved by running. Sources > Scan for External Changes.

Comment: @jradxl It worked for me! Your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run from menu

Source > Scan for External Changes

It worked for me.